# ¿Como almacenar datos en un array y que no muestre los espacios nulos?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando almacenar una "dirección" en un **array con 150 espacios**, esto se almacena en un documento txt y el problema es que al abrir el documento txt la dirección me **muestra los espacios sobrantes**.

El código es el siguiente:

```
struct cliente{
    char dni[9];
    char nombre[20];
    char apellidos[80];
    char direccion[150]
}clientes[max_clientes]; 



void aniadirCliente()
{

    if(clientes[n].dni[0]=='\0'){
        printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
        gets(nom_archivo);
        fflush(stdin);
        //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
        archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"rw");
        if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "rw")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n\nEl archivo no existe.");
            system("cls"); //En windows limpia pantalla
        }else{
            int i;
            printf("\n\nArchivo cargado correctamente.");
            for(i=0; i<max_clientes;i++){
                //Los datos teneis que ponerlos con _ porque no coge los espacios. Ej: Pelegrin_Castillo
                fscanf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);
            }
            for(i=0;i<max_clientes;i++){
                if(clientes[i].dni[0]=='\0'){
                    //Crear un nuevo cliente, lo mismo que antes los espacios con _
                    puts("DNI:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].dni);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", clientes[i].dni);

                    puts("Nombre:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].nombre);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].nombre);

                    puts("Apellidos:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);

                    puts("Direccion:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }

}
            fclose(archivo);
            system("cls");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ésto te debería de funcionar. Cambia el modo de abrir el archivo de "rw" por "a+" entre otros cambios, como == por !=, suprimir la linea de abrir documento duplicada, etc... Había varios errores en tu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max_clientes 50

struct cliente{
    char dni[9];
    char nombre[20];
    char apellidos[80];
    char direccion[150]
}clientes[max_clientes];
FILE *archivo;

int main() {
    aniadirCliente();
    return 0;
}


void aniadirCliente()
{
    int i;
    char nom_archivo[50];

    printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
    gets(nom_archivo);
    fflush(stdin);

    //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
    if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "a+")) != NULL) {

        for(i=0;i<max_clientes;i++){
                //Crear un nuevo cliente, lo mismo que antes los espacios con _
                puts("DNI:");
                scanf("%s", &clientes[i].dni);
                fprintf(archivo, "DNI: %s\n", &clientes[i].dni);

                puts("Nombre:");
                scanf("%s", &clientes[i].nombre);
                fprintf(archivo, "Nombre: %s\n", &clientes[i].nombre);

                puts("Apellidos:");
                scanf("%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);
                fprintf(archivo, "Apellidos: %s\n", &clientes[i].apellidos);

                puts("Direccion:");
                scanf("%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                fprintf(archivo, "Direccion: %s\n", &clientes[i].direccion);
                break;
                }

    }
        fclose(archivo);
        system("cls");

}
```

Como está ahí puesto, no te imprimirá los espacios en blanco sobrantes que comentas.